# How to get known properties of an object nested in another object?

Tags: javascript

Keys of `books` object are automatically generated by Firebase.

```
{
  books: {
    -LKsSspLai8tTppJjSiE: {
      author: 'Author 1',
      name: 'Book 1'
    },
    -LKsS15TMhGRQXlZZlkE: {
      author: 'Author 2',
      name: 'Book 2'
    },
    {}, {}...
  }
  timestamp: 1535579350
}
```

I have no problem with accessing first level properties, but how can I create an array from `books` object for further looping over `authors` and `names`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, I want to render a list of books and populate it with those properties. I tried .keys/values/entries and .map/forEach and for/in loops and weren't able to get what I need. Thought it would be lot easier.

Comment: @Igniter Show us what you've tried.  `Object.values` will work fine for this so you must be missing something else. Are you doing `Object.values(response.books)`? where `response` is what you're getting from firebase?

Comment: You didn't specify how should your end-result 'array' look like - the object books as is, is fully iterate/able

Comment: @david, yes exactly wating for a promise - I'm using Firebase in React and it's kind of difficult to recreate the environment and reproduce the results I'm getting.

Comment: Are you doing this inside the `then` handler of the promise? You need to do that for the result to be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object.values(books), then loop through that array.

```
Object.values(books).forEach( (book) => {
    // now you have book.author and book.name
});
```

Comment: No, you don't have `book.author` and `book.name`. `book` will be the keys `"-LKsSspLai8tTppJjSiE"`, ...

Comment: This won't work, Object.keys( books ) would just return an array of the keys, not the values.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I wasn't thinking clearly. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: But it might not work in IE browser. https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-values I recommend you using Object.keys.

Comment: To expand on @JaeWooWoo's comment, you can do `Object.keys(books).map(key => books[key])` to get the values without using Object.values directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an object's values into an array (as you asked), you could use lodash:

```js
const a = {
  books: {
    "-LKsSspLai8tTppJjSiE": {
      author: 'Author 1',
      name: 'Book 1'
    },
    "-LKsS15TMhGRQXlZZlkE": {
      author: 'Author 2',
      name: 'Book 2'
    },
  },
  timestamp: 1535579350
}

console.log( _.values(a.books) )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Javid, I got `ReferenceError: books is not defined` there. Should be vanilla method though.

Comment: I mean your code sandbox, it gives an error, please check

Comment: Reload / retry, I may have been editing when you loaded it.

Comment: Nice output, but are there more native methods?

Comment: Why the downvotes with? no explanation? This is a suitable solution.

Comment: I think it's a combination of you using a 4kb library to do something that's built in and the link to a 3rd party site to show working code. Stackoverflow has a fiddle thing built in now, you can access it by clicking the icon that has <> in it.

Comment: @Igniter - Yes, you could use Object.values, but sometimes it gives you back more than you bargain for when you're using native Javascript objects (may not matter in the case of these Firebase objects). Lodash has the advantage of being lightweight, but also letting you chain together multiple commands to get the output you want (for example, you could quickly figure out the count of people with the same name or get a unique list of authors sorted alphabetically) by just adding a little more code.

Comment: @david Few projects aren't already pulling in libraries like underscore and lodash. It's a better and more practical approach in many cases where you need to do more than just get the values. But if that's downvote worthy, so be it.